# $\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}y\:y^n \exp\left[\alpha \sqrt{1-y}\right]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Let $n$ be a positive integer (or zero) and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, then consider

$$
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}y\:y^n \exp\left[\alpha  \sqrt{1-y}\right]
\end{equation},
$$

We may expand the exponential and then the squared root in power series, but then the expression will be in terms of the remaining sums which is not very useful. I wonder if it's possible to write down an answer in terms of special and/or elemnetary functions.

Comment: The substitution $u = \sqrt{1-y}$, $y = 1-u^2$, $dy = -2u\,du$ should lead to an answer in terms of elementary functions (for $t\le 1$, anyway).

Comment: @tuna, Sorry, I made a mistake. It is defined from $t=0$ to $t=1$. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$I_n=\int_0^1y^n e^{\alpha  \sqrt{1-y}}\,dy$$ A @tuna commented, let $\sqrt{1-y}=x$ which makes
$$I_n=2\int_0^1 x \left(1-x^2\right)^n e^{\alpha  x}\,dx$$ Now, use the binomial expansion to face a series of integrals
$$J_k=\int_0^1 x^{2k+1}e^{\alpha  x}\,dx$$ and think about the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that the final answer can be written in terms of Bessel and Struve function.